# excel swap data, range,

Tags: excel, vba, range, transformation, swap

is there any simple way to swap the data in the form of series as attached 1 to attached 2

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please show how you have done it so far, simple or not. Then we can discuss how to simplify it.

Comment: *"is there any simple way ..."*  What do you mean by "simple".  For me it would be simple to do using Power Query or VBA.

Answer (score 0):

you can use simple loops:

```
Sub swapper()
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim r As Range 'destination row
    Dim s As Range 'source
    Dim a As Range 'source row
    Set s = Range("A12:C14")
    Set r = Range("A17")
    For Each a In s.Rows
        For n = a.Cells(1, 2).value To a.Cells(1, 3).value
            r.value = a.Cells(1, 1).value
            r.offset(0, 1).value = n
            Set r = r.offset(1, 0)
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: than you so much, 
I had no idea it could be done that way
-- n = a.Cells(1, 2).value To a.Cells(1, 3).value

Answer (score -1):

Use pivot tables, can be very helpful for these types of data.